# Is there a lighter way to implement "object stops when hit wall" without relying on Dynamic gameobjects in Unity3D (2D)?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection, rigidbody

I am currently using a Dynamic GameObject for my entities, but I feel as if that will risk slowing down the game on weaker hardware (especially when there are hundreds of entities). Not only that, but the setting's reliance on forces may cause hard-to-diagnose issues on my velocity-setting centric game design.

After several days of trying to fudge a solution to use Kinematics, I gave up and set everything to Dynamic again. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: signed distance field collision detection

Comment: Can you tell us more about what these entities need to do in your game? The more context you give, the better we can tailor solutions to serve that context well.

Comment: If you don't need physics for anything else, you can use `[CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html)`, which despite the misleading name is applicable to anything that should moved by code but stop when it collides with something.